# Unable to install pip in python server

Tags: python

I have Python version 3.8.3 installed and While trying to install the library "tweepy" using

```
[pip install tweepy]
```

it says [pip: command not found]. I tried to reinstall python and it did not work.

Comment: What is the system you're using?

Comment: is pip installed on your system?

Comment: Go to your python installation directory and under scripts folder you will find pip.exe from there open CMD and run this

Comment: If there is no pip.exe under scripts then pip was not install during python installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using macosx -

Try using easy_install

```
[sudo easy_install pip]
```

Also After installing python 3.x you need to use the command pip3 - not only pip

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pip using

```
#cent os
sudo yum install python-pip
Or
Sudo apk add python-pip
Or 
Sudo apt install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are solutions if you're using linux.

If you're on windows, here are the steps to do.

1. Download get-pip.py (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. CD to the directory where you have the get-pip.py script
3. Execute: python get-pip.py
4. Check that it has been installed: pip --version